# How to use Javascript to change li to active on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use Javascript to change the class of li to "active" upon clicking on the list item. I tried to implement the code that I have linked to & pasted below, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Could somebody help me figure out where I have gone wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/clairedj/d9m7h0oe/

HTML:

```
<ul id="homelist">
    <li class="hlist1">
        <div class="tybtns">
            <img alt="Touchpoint Map" src=
            "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/buttons.jpg">
            <ul class="touch">
                <li class="t1"><span></span> <img alt="Touch 1 Direct Mail"
                src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t1a.jpg">
                 <img alt="Touch 1 Direct Mail" src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t1b.jpg">
                </li>
                <li class="t2"><span></span> <img alt="Touch 2 Email" src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t2a.jpg">
                 <img alt="Touch 2 Email" src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t2b.jpg">
                </li>
                <li class="t3"><span></span> <img alt=
                "Touch 3 Personalized URL" src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t3a.jpg">
                 <img alt="Touch 3 Personalized URL" src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t3b.jpg">
                </li>
                <li class="t4">
                    <span></span> <a class="playSound"><img alt=
                    "Touch 4 Mobile-Text" src=
                    "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/touch4_01-e1460158229527.jpg">
                    </a> <img alt="Touch 4 Mobile-Text" src=
                    "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/t4text-e1460564587270.jpg">
                    </li>
                <li class="t5"><span></span> <img alt=
                "Touch 5 Social Media" src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t5a.jpg">
                 <img alt="Touch 5 Social Media" src=
                "http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t5b.jpg">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#homelist li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.tybtns {
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 765px;
    position: relative;
}

#homelist li.hlist1 .tybtns img {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#homelist .tybtns li {
    list-style: outside none none;
}

#homelist .tybtns li span {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 70px;
    left: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    width: 70px;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t2 span {
    left: 176px;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t3 span {
    left: 345px;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t4 span {
    left: 513px;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t5 span {
    left: 682px;
}

#homelist li.hlist1 .tybtns li img {
    display: none;
}

#homelist li.hlist1 .tybtns li.active img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t1 span::after,#homelist .tybtns li.t2 span::after,#homelist .tybtns li.t3 span::after,#homelist .tybtns li.t4 span::after,#homelist .tybtns li.t5 span::after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    bottom: -20px;
    content: "Touch 1 - Direct Mail";
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    left: -25px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 110px;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t2 span::after {
    content: "Touch 2 - Email";
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t3 span::after {
    content: "Touch 3 - pURL";
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t4 span::after {
    content: "Touch 4 - Mobile";
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t5 span::after {
    content: "Touch 5 - Social";
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t1.active span::after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bad636;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t2.active span::after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9f2065;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t3.active span::after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f7941f;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t4.active span::after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1b7ba3;
}

#homelist .tybtns li.t5.active span::after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #606062;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".touch span").click(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        (this).parent().removeClass('active');
    } else {
        (".touch span").parent().removeClass('active');
        (this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your code?

Comment: You're code works but you forgot to enable JQuery in the 'JavaScript' section.

Comment: in jsfiddle, click on the word Javascript and from Frameworks & Extensions select Jquery 3.1.0  and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You need to load jquery in your fiddle.
You can enable it on the settings cog in the javascript section
[image: JSFiddle Javascript settings]

Select your preferred version of jquery from the frameworks & extensions dropdown and you should be good to go.
Everything worked and looked great for me once I changed this setting!

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan Seed mentioned, you'll need to add jQuery to your JSFiddle in order for it to work. I'd like to also add that you can simplify your jQuery code...

```
$(".touch span").click(function() {
  $('.touch span').parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

This removes the need for conditionals by removing the `active` class from all `.touch span` parents before re-adding it to the particular parent of the one that was clicked.

Answer (score -1):

It is very hard to click inside an empty span, probably you wanted to make a different markup, i.e.

```
<li class="t1">
    <span>
        <img src="http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t1a.jpg" alt="Touch 1 Direct Mail" />
        <img src="http://www.allegraaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/t1b.jpg" alt="Touch 1 Direct Mail" />
    </span>
</li>
```

You've also forgot to call JQuery in the following line: `$(".touch span").parent().removeClass('active');` - your code has no `$` in the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

if you whant use some `jQuery` resource, you must call is to your page. Doing it, it will be ok. Your code is right. :)

Here is you link, now with `jQuery` linked.

https://jsfiddle.net/d9m7h0oe/3/